# preserve HTML tags in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, xmlhttprequest

Suppose an XML has a text that contains HTML tags like `<br/>`, `<b>` and `<i>`.

Can I get the data with `XMLHttpRequest` and preserve those HTML tags?

#### text.xml

```xml
<div>
  <p>Foo bar <br/>foobar <b>bold</b> <i>italic</i></p>
</div>
```

#### index.html

```html
<p id="text"></p>
```

#### script.js

```js
var request;

function sendInfo() {
    var url = "text.xml";
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    try {
        request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send();
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("Unable to connect to server");
    }
}

function getInfo() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        var val = request.responseText;
        document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = val;
    }
}

sendInfo();
```

Result in the **Browser**:

```html
Foo bar<br/>
foobar bold italic<br/><br/>
```

The `<br/>` tag seems to be preserved but `<b>` and `<i>` have no effect.

The HTML in Chrome's Elements tab looks like this:

```html
<p id="text">
  <div>
    <p>
      "Foo bar "
      <br>
      "foobar "
      <b>bold</b> 
      <i>italic</i>
    </p>
  </div>
</p>
```

Am I on the right track with this? What do I miss?

Comment: Why do you think `<b>` and `<i>` are not preserved? They're in the Elements tab.

Comment: @drake7 Hey man it seems to work perfect ! NO ISSUE

Comment: If the text doesn't appare bold or italic, it could be a CSS issue.

Comment: Yes I can confirm it was a CSS issue. I had a reset.css that somehow nullified those tags. I am trying to understand how... Thank you all very much for pointing out that the code should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**. As pointed out, the code works.

It was a CSS issue.

Specifically the `b, u, i { font: inherit }` in my
**reset.css** in the `index.html` (in my dev environment).

Once I commented it out, the tags where applied as expected.

(My bad that I didn't test the simplified code I used for this question.)